# How can I hardcode a file as a byte array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have to create some functionality that performs operations on byte arrays, that will be provided by other parts of the program. For testing and development, I've been provided the arrays as files, and simply use them as such:

```
unsigned char frame_bytes[FRAME_SIZE];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.xyz", "rb");
fread(frame_bytes, sizeof(unsigned char), FRAME_SIZE, fp);
// test the functionality that operates on frame_bytes
```

Now I have to test the code on an embedded environment without a file system. Is there any straightforward way to hardcode this file as a byte array?

Comment: Split the loading of file into buffer and processing the buffer. Then you can read your buffers from files or from byte arrays.

Comment: look for a tool called `bin2c` it will create a `C` array from you binary file and you can compile it into your code

Comment: Another alternative to the programs mentioned by others is `xxd` which, with the `-i` flag, creates a header file with an array representing the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HxD (which is very useful in itself) from https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ has the option to export as a C array which you would then be able to compile into your application.

I have no affiliation with HxD other than being a happy user.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know it could do this. I've been copying the hex bytes out of HxD, pasting them, replacing every space with ", 0x" then pasting that into an array. (With an extra "0x" on the front)

Comment: @ThomasJager Assuming you've got the same version as me, File->Export->C does it.